# Из-за YoutubeActivity не могу использовать метод getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Tags: java, android

```
public class PostDetailActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener, YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

TextView mSongNamev, mSingerNamev, mComposer, mAuthor, mSongText;

YouTubePlayerView playerView;
String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAYHLYDF30xl_ArDlkiAeVnYtBPhNRBJYQ";
String Video_Id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //YoutubePlayerAPi
    playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.playerview);
    playerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);


    //Initiliazing
    mSongNamev = findViewById(R.id.textViewSongNameGet);
    mSingerNamev = findViewById(R.id.textViewSingerNameGet);
    mComposer = findViewById(R.id.textViewComposerGet);
    mAuthor = findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthorGet);
    mSongText = findViewById(R.id.textViewSongText);


    //get Data From intent
    String SongName = getIntent().getStringExtra("songname");
    String SingerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("singername");
    String ComposerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("composername");
    String AuthorName = getIntent().getStringExtra("authorname");
    String SongText = getIntent().getStringExtra("songtext");
    Video_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ytblink");

    //Set data to views
    mSongNamev.setText(SongName);
    mSingerNamev.setText(SingerName);
    mComposer.setText(ComposerName);
    mAuthor.setText(AuthorName);
    mSongText.setText(SongText);
}
```

Если поменять на AppCompatActivity, то ютуб ругается.Что делать?

Есть варианты думаю прописать YoutubeApi в другом классе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` руками в ваш `R.layout.activity_post_detail`
И в коде установите его в `supportActionBar`. Проверьте еще, что бы стили не пытались поствить тулбар на эту активити.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```